# Silverlight Business Template Type Application using WCF Authentication and custom schema, not the schema generated by aspnet_regsql.exe tool

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, authentication, service

I have a scenario and I really need your help. I have a Silverlight Business Application which comes with a preconfigured essential Gui like Login, ApplicationName etc. I configured a database with aspnet_regsql.exe and started using this database with my application like registering user, authenticating users etc. But this is not the solution I am looking for. I have following problems which this template doesn't fullfill.

1. I have custom tables and a custom gui for creating users (of different types) which means   I can't go with asp.net's tables (Is it so?)
2. I want my authentication web service to be a wcf service and be served on a server which is supposed to serve other services.
3. I want to create my own rules and I want to assign these roles to user's based upon my own GUI.
4. I want my WebContext to work with my wcf service and give me all the things it is currently giving in case of Silverlight Business Application Template, like isAthenticated, isLoggedIn, isLoggingIn etc.

How should I move on, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could you reformat the title of your question so that it's not just a collection of tags, but an actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not really, you can use the original authentication service (deriving from AuthenticationBase if memory serves), but need to replace the role and membership providers in the web config, with your custom ones. That way you can use your own tables.
2. WCF Ria provides built in authentication, it's a pretty good solution and - in my experience - works pretty well.
3. You can do that with custom role and membership providers, whatever you use is up to you.
4. The Authentication service from WCF Ria generates a WebContext object client-side. it contains the functionality you need.

Comment: Maciek, I need to deploy my services on a different server not the one hosting my silverlight application, will it then be possible with RIA Services. Secondly, can you please point me to some good resources, blog for this if you know. Thanks for replying.

Comment: 1. Yes it is possible, but Ria services are only hostable on IIS. 2. This scenario will cause cross-domain access issues - so be aware of it. 3. Ask google.